# Why am I getting this error ? "unresolved external symbol"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

This is the error I have been getting the whole time and I've been trying to figure out how to fix it but have failed. I am asking if anyone can point me to the right direction.

```
 WorldServer fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
WorldServer error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class CItemElem * __thiscall CLinkedItemMgr::GetLinkedItem(unsigned long)" (?GetLinkedItem@CLinkedItemMgr@@QAEPAVCItemElem@@K@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CDPSrvr::OnLinkedItem(class CAr &,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned char *,unsigned long)" (?OnLinkedItem@CDPSrvr@@AAEXAAVCAr@@KKPAEK@Z)
WorldServer error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall CLinkedItemMgr::AddLinkedItem(class CItemElem *)" (?AddLinkedItem@CLinkedItemMgr@@QAEHPAVCItemElem@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CDPSrvr::OnLinkedItem(class CAr &,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned char *,unsigned long)" (?OnLinkedItem@CDPSrvr@@AAEXAAVCAr@@KKPAEK@Z)
```

This is the .h

```
#ifndef __ITEM_LINK__H
#define __ITEM_LINK__H
class CLinkedItemMgr
{
private:
    CLinkedItemMgr(){ m_dwLinkedItemCount = 0;};
    ~CLinkedItemMgr(){};
    DWORD m_dwLinkedItemCount;
public:
    map<DWORD,CItemElem*> m_mapLinkedItems;

    static CLinkedItemMgr *GetInstance()
    {
        static CLinkedItemMgr instance;
        return &instance;
    }
    int AddLinkedItem(CItemElem *pItem);
    CItemElem *GetLinkedItem(DWORD dwIndex);
};
#endif
```

this is the .cpp

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "ItemLink.h"
int CLinkedItemMgr::AddLinkedItem(CItemElem *pItem)
{
    if(!pItem)
        return 0;
    m_mapLinkedItems.insert(make_pair<DWORD,CItemElem*>(++m_dwLinkedItemCount,pItem));
    return m_dwLinkedItemCount;
}
CItemElem *CLinkedItemMgr::GetLinkedItem(DWORD dwIndex)
{
    map<DWORD,CItemElem*>::iterator it = m_mapLinkedItems.find(dwIndex);
    if(it == m_mapLinkedItems.end())
        return FALSE;
    return it->second;
}
```

Comment: Where you define `AddLinkedItem`?

Comment: Your include guards are reserved identifiers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the cpp here.

```
#ifdef __ITEM_LINK
#include "ItemLink.h"
```

`#ifdef __ITEM_LINK` means "only process the code below if `__ITEM_LINK` is defined"

And in your case, it is **not defined**.  It only gets defined when `"ItemLink.h"` is included, and `"ItemLink.h"` only gets included if it's already defined.  You've prevented either from happening first.

Remove the `#ifdef` line.

Comment: i've added the .cpp as well

Comment: alright thank you i will test it right now.

Comment: I removed the ifdef line but it seems I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @user2205389 Please edit your question to show exactly what the code and error message look like now.

Comment: i pasted again the error but i'm pretty sure it was the same one as the old one.

Comment: i have edited it per your instructions.

Comment: @user2205389 I copied your new code and it builds successfully.  I recommend visiting the link in the first comment to your question.

Comment: thank you for helping I was able to figure out the problem :) I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a linking problem.
The compiler knows your class has a function called `GetLinkedItem` but can't find any definition of that function anywhere. Are you linking properly when compiling your executable?
I bet stopping the compiler before linking doesn't trigger any error.
(e.g. g++ -c ItemLink.cpp).

i'm going to ask the help of someone who's accustomed to visual studio to elaborate more :D
anyway, compiling requires three major steps:
1) applying preprocessor directives, parsing the source code, looking for syntax errors and the like
2) creating an object file from source code (something half-way between source code and executable)
3) linking all the object files making up your project in one executable

your compiling chain fails at the third step.
the compiler expects a certain function to be defined in some .cpp (that has become an object file at step 2 of compiling chain) but can't find it anywhere.

and it can't find it because of that #ifdef in the .cpp file, which tells the preprocessor NOT TO INCLUDE your definitions, since __ITEM_LINK is not defined

i see you changed the .cpp in your question by the way

Comment: Mind eplaining to me what you mean by stopping the compiler? I'm using Visual Studio 2003

Comment: i elaborated more in my answer, hope you find it helpful

Comment: Alright I'll check to see if i missed anywhere on defining ITEM_LINK

Comment: The code displayed in your question should compile, though, since those #ifndefs have been removed. Does it?

Comment: thank you for helping I was able to figure out the problem :) I appreciate the help

Comment: what about an up for me? :D

Comment: sorry I don't have enough votes to do that. :)